# Problems building an R package (NAs introduced by coercion)

Tags: r, shell, package

I have written the [Boggler](https://github.com/dcomtois/Boggler) package which includes a [Play.Boggle()](https://github.com/dcomtois/Boggler/blob/master/R/play_boggle.R) function that calls, on line 87, a [progress bar](https://github.com/dcomtois/Boggler/blob/master/R/progress_bar.R) script using `shell`:

```
shell(cmd = sprintf('Rscript.exe R/progress_bar.R "%i"', time.limit + 1), wait=FALSE)
```

Everything works fine when sourcing the files individually and then calling the main `Play.Boggle()` function, but when I try to check/build the package (under Win7-64 using RStudio), I get a failure message -- here's what the `00install.out` reports:

```
** preparing package for lazy loading
Warning in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : NAs introduced by coercion
Error in time.limit:0 : NA/NaN argument
```

To make sure the argument "%i" (time.limit + 1) was correctly passed to the `progress_bar.R`, I added a `cat(time.limit)` to the script (commenting the rest out to make sure the package would build without any errors) and directed its output to a log file like this:

```
'Rscript.exe R/progress_bar.R "%i" > out.log'
```

Conclusion: the time limit is indeed passed along as expected. So I can't figure out why I get this "NA/NaN argument" error message. It must have something to do with lazy loading, concept that I haven't fully got my head around yet.

So my question is: **what can I do to successfully check/build this package with full functionality (including progress_bar.R)?**

Note: On github, the progress_bar.R script is there but all its content is commented out so that the package can successfully be installed. The shell(...) function call is still active, doing nothing but executing an empty script.

Comment: Why do you create your command bar in such a convoluted way? Instead of calling a script you should make the content of progress_bar.R a function in your package. The warning is probably created from `time.limit <- as.numeric(commandArgs(trailingOnly = TRUE)[1])`.

Comment: Convoluted in what sense? I like the graphical aspect of tk's progressbar, and I can't just call a function, as this process will monopolize the interpreter -- it needs to be run in parallel in a way or another.

Comment: neither `time.limit` nor the quotes are in cause here, I've checked that thoroughly already; I mean if I comment out only the tk part of the progress_bar.R script, everything works fine. Plus, don't forget that sourcing the files individually, without packaging everything, works perfectly fine (including the progress bar).

Comment: AFAIK all .R files are sourced when you build a package. Who knows what `commandArgs` returns then ...

Comment: Yeah it has something to do with that, but I'm not sure what it's doing. The reference to NaN seems pretty cryptic to me. Although I just got an idea...

Comment: That's not cryptic. `commandArgs(trailingOnly = TRUE)[1]` is not something that can be turned into a numeric, resulting in `NA` from `as.numeric`. Thus `:` tells you that it was passed an `NA` value.  Instead of a `shell` call, I'd use package parallel for the parallelization.

Comment: I totally disagree. It is turned into a numeric as expected, just not when building. I just added a condition that if(time.limit %in% c(NA, NaN)), I set time.limit to some minimal number. And it builds now.

Comment: Well, if you are happy with that ... I still think, you approach is not the best way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem arises when trying to build or check, in which case all R scripts are executed, as pointed out by Roland. A simple workaround allows the package to check/build without any problems. The fix is just to add to the `progress_bar.R` the following lines after it tries to recuperate the commandargs (lines 10-11):

```
if(time.limit %in% c(NA, NaN))
  time.limit <- 10 # or any minimal number
```

There's surely other ways to go about this. But this being a game programmed for fun, I'll happily go with that patch. Hopefully this can be of help to someone down the road and I won't have wasted 50 precious rep points in vain for that bounty! :D